# How can I create a different URL for every new Object

Tags: javascript, url, server, backend

I have built this site "https://supsurvey.herokuapp.com/SurveyCreate.html"

You create a survey and then it redirects you to a unique URL
https://supsurvey.herokuapp.com/SurveyPage.html#718807c9-3a5b-4745-b953-511afef5e073

In the surveyCreate page I have location.assign (`SurveyPage.html#${survey.id}`) which is linked to SurveyPage.js and from there I extract the uuid4 using currentUrl.split (#) and then I send a get request to my server which is built in NODE-JavaScript (only for strong survey objects in MongoDB) for the correct survey OBJECT and display it to the user.

I want so so that after you press create Survey you will be redirected to

https://supsurvey.herokuapp.com/SurveyPage/718807c9-3a5b-4745-b953-511afef5e073

So instead of .html#{uuid} to /{uuid}

How do I do that?

I have tried changing to location.assign (`SurveyPage/${survey.id}`)
but it fail because it doesn't find the file without the .html extension

I also tried location.assign (`SurveyPage.html/${survey.id}`) which also doesn't work.

Comment: you need a templating engine and url rewriter - since you are using NODE for backend that can all be done using EXPRESS server

Comment: When you load a URL with `SurveyPage.html` you're (most likely) directly referencing a file that lives on the server's file system. What you probably want to do is create a `route` that includes your path and a variable, such as `/SurveyPage/:surveyId` which points to a component or template that renders what you want the user to see after fetching the data related to the `surveyId`. It's a high level explanation but hopefully will give you the basic idea.

Comment: man I think I got it, 
and in the route  ( /SurveyPage/:surveyId ) get method 
I do something like that 
 res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../public/surveyPage.html")); if so how do I send the survey as well

Comment: having a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'" bug the page loads but not the js file nvm manged to fix that by serving the static folder first

Answer (score 0):

since you are using NODE for backend - you can build your app using express

https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.baseUrl

allows for api like route rewriting to accomplish what you want

can also be done using the more robust Hapi server

https://hapi.dev/

can be done on any language really

slimphp works great for php apps

http://www.slimframework.com/